# Subset in XPath

Tags: xpath, sequence, schematron

In xPath if one has sequence1 = sequence2, it returns true if there is at least one element in sequence1 which is also in sequence2. I need something which allows me to test if all elements of sequence1 exist in sequence2 (the set of values of sequence1 is a subset of the set of values in sequence2).

Is this feasible?

Comment: It would be good to give a concrete example. Are you asking about sequences of *nodes*, or is the question about any sequences? How is "equality" defined? Does it have identity-based semantics, or does it have value-based semantics?

Comment: Also, it is more precise to speak about "subset". Subsequence implies same ordering and this *isn't* what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the [double negation law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**:

```
not($seq1[not(. = $seq2)])
```

**Alternatively, and much more efficiently -- for sequence of nodes and node-identity based equality semantics: (O(N) vs O(N^2))**:

```
count($seq1 | $seq2) = count($seq2)
```

---

**II. XPath 2.0**

**For a sequence of nodes (node-identity - based equality semantics)**:

```
not($seq1 except $seq2)
```

**and an efficient expression for sequence of values**:

```
count(distinct-values(($seq1, $seq2))) eq count(distinct-values($seq2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in XPath 1.0:

```
not($sequence1[not(. = $sequence2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use every to check if every element is in sequence2

```
every $x in $sequence1 satisfies $x = $sequence2
```

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: well, it would be the job of the query optimizer to change it into the most efficient version.

Comment: BeniBela: Do you truly believe that the Optimizer can replace this O(N^2) expression with an O(N) one? :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: it could, even with a simple rule. If a constant sequence is used for comparison within a big loop, replace that sequence by a hash. => O(n) * O(1) hash lookups

Comment: BeniBela: Smile :) And for "non-constant" sequence? I will never rely on what a particular optimizer would know about "constant" and about "big loop"